# Short circuiting a list of functions returns \/

Tags: scala, scalaz, either

So I have an expensive method with this signature

```
def func(param: Int): \/[String, Int]
```

I am trying to loop over a list of params and returns `\/[String, List[Int]]` but stop the loop whenever the method returns `-\/`.

I come up with this:

```
scala> def func(i: Int) = {
     |   if( i > 1 ) { println{"!!"} ;"error".left[Int]}
     |   else i.right[String]
     | }
func: (i: Int)scalaz.\/[String,Int]

scala> val toList = (dis: scalaz.\/[String,Int]) => {dis.map(i => List(i))}
toList: scalaz.\/[String,Int] => scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = <function1>

scala> val composed = (func _) andThen toList
composed: Int => scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = <function1>

scala> (1 to 3).toList.foldLeftM(List[Int]().right[String]){(dis, i) =>
     |   for{
     |     a <- dis
     |     b <- composed(i)
     |   } yield a |+| b
     | }
<console>:17: error: no type parameters for method foldLeftM: (f: (scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]], Int) => G[scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]]])(implicit M: scalaz.Monad[G])G[scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]]] exist so that it can be applied to arguments ((scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]], Int) => scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : (scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]], Int) => scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]]
 required: (scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]], Int) => ?G[scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]]]

              (1 to 2).toList.foldLeftM(List[Int]().right[String]){(dis, i) =>
                                       ^
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]], Int) => scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]]
 required: (scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]], Int) => G[scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]]]
              (1 to 2).toList.foldLeftM(List[Int]().right[String]){(dis, i) =>
                                                                            ^
```

What's the `G[_]` here and what's the correct result type in `foldLeftM` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by noted two mistake I made:

1. misunderstood about type of initial/carried over value, it should be `List[Int]` instead of `\/`
2. one has to explicit declare type parameter of `foldLeftM`

   ```
   scala> def func(i: Int) = {
    |   if( i > 1 ) { println{"!!"} ;"error".left[Int]}
    |   else i.right[String]
    | }
   func: (i: Int)scalaz.\/[String,Int]

   scala> val toList = (dis: scalaz.\/[String,Int]) => {dis.map(i => List(i))}
   toList: scalaz.\/[String,Int] => scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = <function1>

   scala> val composed = (func _) andThen toList
   composed: Int => scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = <function1>

   scala> val f = (dis: List[Int], i: Int) => composed(i).map(r => dis |+| r)
   f: (List[Int], Int) => scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = <function2>

   scala> (1 to 4).toList.foldLeftM[({type l[a] = String \/ a})#l, List[Int]](List[Int]())(f)
   !!
   res16: scalaz.\/[String,List[Int]] = -\/(error)
   ```